# Chatter Server and Client

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, tcp

This is the Problem Statement i Was Given :

Design a protocol where a server is responsible to match up two chatt clients. The server listens on a TCP port for upcoming connections. If no client is already connected to the server to be paired, the server accepts the connecting client, and makes it wait for another client. To do that, it sends a message to the connecting client to wait. When recieving this command the client constructs another Server Socket instance to listen on a port . The client then sends a mesagge to the server that contains the port number in which the newly created server listens on. When another client, C2, seeks a connection with the server while C1 is waiting, the server informs C2 the existence of C1 by sending a message “PEER_LOC $h:$p” to C2, where $h is the host name (or IP address) of C1 and $p is the port number on which C1 is waiting. After C2 receives this message, it seeks a connection to C1 using the obtained information.Clients get the messages from users. The two clients then exchange messages until either party sends an end of stream” (Ctrl-D in Linux). Their conservation is then terminated.Sophisticated methods may employ multiple threads, timeouts, etc., and is not required in this problem.

My issues is connecting two clients to my Server. I run my server program and then two other clients classes that are duplicated of each other only with different names. I can connect to one of them only the other one just seems to wait forever.

Theses are my classes I run.

The server:

```
package chatserver2;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.*;
   // import all the class that you will need for functionailty

// extends jframe to develop gui's in java
public class Server {

    private static ObjectOutputStream output; // stream data out
    private static ObjectInputStream input; // stream data in
    private static ServerSocket server;
    private static Socket connection; // socket means set up connetion between 2 computers

    private static int n;

//Constructor
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Server obj = new Server();
        obj.RunServer();

        try {
            while (true) {

                Handler obj2 = new Handler();

                obj2.start();
                System.out.println("Accepted connection from "
                        + connection.getInetAddress() + " at port "
                        + connection.getPort());

                n++;
                System.out.println("Count " + n);
            }
        } finally {
            connection.close();
        }

    }

    public Server() {

    }

// run the server after gui created
    public void RunServer() {

        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(6789); // 1st number is port number where the application is located on the server, 2nd number is the amount of people aloud to connect
            while (true) {

                try {
                    waitForConnection(); // wait for a connection between 2 computers 
                    setupStreams();  // set up a stream connection between 2 computers to communicate
                    whileChatting();  // send message to each other
                    // connect with someone and have a conversation
                } catch (EOFException eofException) {

                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ioException) {

            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

//Wait for a connection then display connection information
    private void waitForConnection() {

        try {
            connection = server.accept();
        } catch (IOException ioexception) {

            ioexception.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    // stream function to send and recive data

    private void setupStreams() throws IOException {

        output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream()); // set up pathway to send data out
        output.flush(); // move data away from your machine
        input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream()); // set up pathway to allow data in

    }

// this code while run during chat conversions
    private void whileChatting() throws IOException {

        String message = "WAIT ";
        sendMessage(message);

        do {

            try {

                message = (String) input.readObject(); // stores input object message in a string variable

                System.out.println("Message from Client " + message);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException classnotfoundException) {

            }
        } while (!message.equals("CLIENT - END"));// if user types end program stops

    }

    private void closeChat() {

        try {

            output.close();
            input.close();
            connection.close();

        } catch (IOException ioexception) {

            ioexception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

// send message to the client
    private void sendMessage(String message) {

        try {

            output.writeObject(message);
            output.flush();

            System.out.println("Message to client " + message);

        } catch (IOException ioexception) {

        }

    }

    public static class Handler extends Thread {

        private Socket connection;

        public Handler() {

            String message = "WAIT";

        }

        public void run() {

            System.out.println("Connect" + Server.connection);
            while (true) {

                try {
                    waitForConnection();
                    setupStreams();
                    whileChatting();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

            }

        }

        private void waitForConnection() {

            System.out.println("server" + server);
            try {
                connection = server.accept();
            } catch (IOException ioexception) {

                ioexception.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Connection" + connection);

        }

        private void setupStreams() throws IOException {

            output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream()); // set up pathway to send data out
            output.flush(); // move data away from your machine
            input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream()); // set up pathway to allow data in

        }

        private void whileChatting() throws IOException {

            String message = " You are now connected ";
            sendMessage(message);

            do {

                try {

                    message = (String) input.readObject();

                } catch (ClassNotFoundException classnotfoundException) {

                }
            } while (!message.equals("CLIENT - END"));

        }

        private void closeChat() {

            try {

                output.close();
                input.close();
                connection.close();

            } catch (IOException ioexception) {

                ioexception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        static private void sendMessage(String message) {

            try {

                output.writeObject(message);
                output.flush();

            } catch (IOException ioexception) {

            }

        }

    }
}
```

The and one duplicated client classes C1, or C2:

```
package chatserver2;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
   // import all the class that you will need for functionailty

// extends jframe to develop gui's in java
public class Client1 extends JFrame {

    private JTextField userInput; // 
    private JTextArea theChatWindow; //
    private ObjectOutputStream output; // stream data out
    private ObjectInputStream input; // stream data in

    private Socket connection; // socket means set up connetion between 2 computers

//Constructor
    public Client1() {

    }

// run the server after gui created
    public void RunClient() {

        try {
            connection = new Socket("localhost", 6789);// 1st number is port number where the application is located on the server, 2nd number is the amount of people aloud to connect
            while (true) {

                try {
                    // wait for a connection between 2 computers 
                    setupStreams();  // set up a stream connection between 2 computers to communicate
                    whileChatting();  // send message to each other
                    // connect with someone and have a conversation
                } catch (EOFException eofException) {

                } finally {

                    closeChat();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ioException) {

            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

//Wait for a connection then display connection information
    // stream function to send and recive data
    private void setupStreams() throws IOException {

        output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream()); // set up pathway to send data out
        output.flush(); // move data away from your machine
        input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream()); // set up pathway to allow data in

    }

// this code while run during chat conversions
    private void whileChatting() throws IOException {

        String message = "";

        do {
            // have conversion while the client does not type end
            try {

                message = (String) input.readObject(); // stores input object message in a string variable
                System.out.println("message " + message);
                if (message.equals("WAIT")) {
                    ServerSocket server2 = new ServerSocket(5000);
                    System.out.println("Hello");
                    message = "5000";
                    sendMessage(message);

                }
                System.out.println("From server " + message);

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException classnotfoundException) {

            }
        } while (!message.equals("CLIENT - END"));// if user types end program stops

    }

    private void closeChat() {

        try {

            output.close(); // close output stream
            input.close(); // close input stream
            connection.close(); // close the main socket connection

        } catch (IOException ioexception) {

            ioexception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

// send message to the client
    private void sendMessage(String message) {

        try {

            output.writeObject(" - " + message);
            output.flush(); // send all data out

        } catch (IOException ioexception) {

            theChatWindow.append("\n ERROR: Message cant send");
        }

    }

//
//
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Client1 obj = new Client1();
        obj.RunClient();
    }

}
```

I can connect to the first Client i run the second client waits for ever. Any Suggestions or comments would be appreciated.

Comment: You `accept` is not in any type of loop, so how can it accept more than one client connection?

Comment: Oh, I see you have code in two places that does `accept`

Comment: It is in a while loop isn't . when i call while i call the method whileconnected?

Comment: Your code is blocking, pure and simple. Think through the logic of where you want to use threading to unblock your code flow. This is the key.

Answer (score 1):

Your Handler (which should implement Runnable, not extend Thread) should be created and run in its own background thread each time the server makes a connection, so that all the blocking code goes in there and does not prevent the server from making the next connection. I don't even know why you have that first `while (true)` loop since it does nothing useful. All the important code is in the 2nd while true loop, the one in `runServer()`, and that's where your handler should be created.

Comment: so i should create a instance of handler in the method whileConnected i.e where i do server.accept(port) ?

Comment: I usually get the Socket object obtained from accept, and pass it into a Handler's constructor, and then run my handler in a thread. `new Thread(new MyHandler(myAcceptedSocket)).start();`

Comment: @user7338821: also note that you only need one Client class. Yes you need two instances of this class, but only one class is needed.

Comment: new Code: with your suggested Changes.

Comment: Ok i can connect to two clients with your suggested changes. Is there anything in my code i should change to make the clients be able to chat to the server and be able to send a message between server and client . Also i need a way to independly be able to send a message to either client and a way to send a message to all? How would i do this?

Comment: Client2 obj = new Client2();

Comment: @user7338821: Your questions are too broad and you will need to work this out yourself, I'm afraid.

Comment: Right now im running three programs i need to run only two server and client where should i make these objects in the server class? One object after another and both call.RunClient()